# Why new Date() returns a date with one day offset?

Tags: javascript

when i create a new Date Object from a string i get a wrong date by one day and I dont understand why. I've already verified, that it does not come from timezone difference.

```
var myDate new Date("2016-04-12T22:04:00.000Z")
console.log(myDate);
Wed Apr 13 2016 00:04:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summertime)
```

Comment: Because it's converting it to local time from UTC, as it states it's +2 so you roll into next day as it's 10:04pm.

Comment: is there a way to keep it in UTC?

Comment: *"I've already verified, that it does not come from timezone difference."* - How did you do that?

Comment: @juleee - it's not a matter of "keep"ing it UTC. The date object is the date object and represents a certain time...you can output that time as a local representation or UTC. `.toString()` (what happens when you coerce it to a string directly like you're doing) outputs it as a string representing local time. It sounds like you need to spend some time learning about dates in general: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

The issue is timezones. 22:04:00 in UTC is 00:04:00 in UTC+2.

To get the UTC time, fetch the date parts with `myDate.getUTCHours()`, `mydate.getUTCMinutes()`, etc. See a [full list of `Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the UTC string of your date-

```
var myDate=new Date("2016-04-12T22:04:00.000Z");

myDate.toUTCString()
/* returne value:
Tue, 12 Apr 2016 22: 04: 00 GMT
*/
```

Comment: Hi @kennebec, excuse me to use this question as a place to communicate with you. But I was using your awesome `sharedStart` function but needed help with a modification. If you are available may you please help me - I posted the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49134350/1828637